# Opening links inside a fancybox-window inside the same fancybox window

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fancybox

This is probably not all that difficult, because otherwise iäm sure i wouldv'e found the answer somewhere...

What i want to do i open up a fancybox (the jquery plugin), loading it whith ajax-content, and when i click a link inside it, it loads it with new ajaxcontent, like clicking a link inside a frame.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can either

1. use an iframe inside the fancybox (quickest & easiest, will not use ajax, yet will do as you want and easier SEO), or
2. put a div inside your fancybox, fill it using ajax and `html()`, then bind the contained `a` elements'`click` event to a function which will do the same again. 
   Note that with this second way, you won't automatically have the browser's back button working, SEO's harder, etc.

Comment: Well, yes that would do the trick, of course. But what I actually was after, which a might have been unsucessfull in explaing, is a way to use the sam transitions and resizing that fancybox uses for the gallery function, but use it for other links aswell. thanks though!

Comment: The resizing for an iframe (or ajax-filled div) imply to know the ideal size for the loaded content. If you control this content (it's on your server along with the contained page so it's not restricted by the same origin policy), you can easily talk between your iframe and the parent window to call the reisizing function with the wanted width/height.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I do it:

```
  $('#fancybox-content a').live('hover', function(){
    $(this).fancybox();
  });
```

This will fancybox-animate, including resizing, any link within a fancybox.

Comment: Don't know why you got downvoted, this was the best solution on the page.

Answer (score 1):

I don't code but it seems I have it working after I struggled for 5 hours

If you are opening a new HTML / PHP file with the fancybox this does work (ie9 / ff / safari / chrome)

I created 4 pages - main.php / page1.php / page2.php / page3.php

main.php >> 
Use the fancybox code (style as required)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.openModal").fancybox({
    'autoDimensions'    : false,
    'width'         : 750,
    'height'        : 500,
    'transitionIn'      : 'elastic',
    'transitionOut'     : 'elastic',
    'titleShow'     : false,
    'hideOnContentClick'    : false, 
    });
});
```

{a href="page1.php" class="openModal"}Page Name{/a}

---

user clicks on fancybox link I specified on main.php (I used classes as I have many fancybox links on one page)

All pages have links to each other (but not to main.php)

---

page1.php & page2.php & page3.php - MUST have the same identical code you used in the main page (otherwise you'd get resizing and transition issues)

page1.php

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.openModal").fancybox({
    'autoDimensions'    : false,
    'width'         : 750,
    'height'        : 500,
    'transitionIn'      : 'elastic',
    'transitionOut'     : 'elastic',
    'titleShow'     : false,
    'hideOnContentClick'    : false, 
    });
});
```

- {a href="page1.php" class="openModal"}Page Name{/a}
- {a href="page2.php" class="openModal"}Page Name{/a}
- {a href="page3.php" class="openModal"}Page Name{/a}

---

Works perfectly for me - links via fancybox Modal, to a page and then links to page within Modal, links to another page within Modal (I have gone 6 links in).

Must be an "easier" way (correct word would be "right") - but this workaround is my solution

I haven't tested with forms - and I cannot get "javascript: history.go(-1)" to work -

so ONLY goes forward (help with that would be AWESOME)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `onComplete` (1.3 or lower) or `afterShow` (2.0+) callback.

Just run the same code there as you would on your page to activate the fancybox.

I like to make it functional, so you can easily re-call it.

```
function initFancybox() {
  $("a.openModal").fancybox({options..., onComplete: initFancybox });
}
```

You can also do it manually and use a selector if you only want to activate fancybox links within the newly-opened fancybox. This might be slightly more efficient.

```
function initFancybox(selector) {
  if (selector == null) { selector = ""; }
  $(selector+" a.openModal").fancybox({options..., 
    onComplete: function() { initFancybox("#fancybox-content"); }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes what you need is a frame (iframe). Fancybox has to know that the content its loading should be treated like a frame
so you might want to use a

`$('#contentclassorid').fancybox({
   type: "iframe"
});`